# Fragment/Activity Best Practice

Tags: android, android-fragments

I set up my application in the following way and am curious if it's considered "best practice." I have two activities and two fragments. Activity 1 launches and immediately uses Fragment 1 to display a RecyclerView of items. An Item is clicked in the Fragment, it's communicated back to the Activity through an interface, some logic occurs and Activity 2 is launched, which immediately uses Fragment 2 to display the detail of the selected item.

I did this because A)I like the logical flow of Activities within an application and 2) I needed to create tablet layouts in which I could use both the Fragments to fill the screen.

The more I'm looking at this thing, I'm thinking why not simply have 1 Activity that manages both of these Fragments? Activity 1 launches Fragment 1, item is clicked, info goes back to Activity, FragmentManager replaces Fragment 1 with Fragment 2.

My question does one of these ways adhere more to "best practices" or are they both fine and it's a matter of choice?

Comment: Oh Boy… you have uncovered a Pandora's box. There is no right or wrong here. Both are ok. I personally try to avoid fragments for an infinite number of reasons. But if you have Tablet layouts, you will want to use them. Regarding whether 1 Act 2 Frags or 2 acts 2 frags, that's more a personal choice in most cases. There aren't "lots of pros/cons" on either side, depending upon your min/max API and what not. If you have 2 activities already working, there's absolutely nothing wrong with that.

Comment: If you use "presenters" and/or dependency injection, then you can off-load a lot of the "logic" outside of the activity/fragment meaning it matters even less what you have, as long as your activity or fragment is only in charge of dealing with the "views" and every time anything happens you tell your "presenter" to deal with it (which communicates back to the activity/fragment) and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

You've not described your problem clear enough to use more than one Activity, other than unrelated data to the list and what happens when you click there.

What you described is a ["master-detail" flow](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/descendant.html#master-detail), and that is a good use case for one Activity and two (or more) Fragments - a list + some detail page. This especially makes sense on larger screens when you can [show those Fragments side-by-side](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

For example, you can have an Activity that holds a navigation screen (whether that be tabs, a drawer, or a bottom view), then everything you navigate to within there is a Fragment.

Otherwise, you redirect to some "settings" page, for example, that is a new Activity, which demonstrates the "[Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)" in your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can go with the single activity - multiple fragments. You can pass data between fragments using bundle as well. Matter of choice also depends on the use case. But fragments are made to use as light weight activity that requires less resources then activity. Most of the things are possible with fragments. So unless it is not required to use activity my choice goes with single activity - multiple fragments.

Comment: > "light weight activity that requires less resources then activity" - what is the source of this? Fragments need a lot of things behind the scenes too, dare I saw they outlive activities if the FragmentManager so desires…